# System.Data.Sqlite and FTS4

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, system.data.sqlite, fts3, fts4

Why when i write a query with fulltext Search syntax like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE TABLENAME MATCH 'ColumnA:word1 OR ColumnB:word2'
```

The query result always return 0 rows?

I'm using VBnet and the latest Ado.net provider from [sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

The problem is when i try the query with and external tool, it works well (with sqlite 3.7.9).

Any clues?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Although System.Data.Sqlite is compiled using `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3` and supports FTS, it doesn't compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS` which enables [Enhanced Query Syntax](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1). And you are using Enhanced Query Syntax in your query, thus it didn't works as you expect.

You need to either modify you query, or do a custom build ([follow build procedures](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki)) of System.Data.Sqlite with `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS` defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i cannot build the mixed assembly version, i have visual studio 2008 pro. I get the error: Error 9 fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'c:\Documents.obj' SQLite.Interop.Static.2008 SQLite.Interop.Static.2008

Comment: follow build procedures: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki

Comment: Thanks petr!!I can compil but even if i change the macro by this i still hav mis interpretation of my enhanced query:     I added the code : <UserMacro
  Name="SQLITE_COMMON_DEFINES"
  Value="SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1;SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1;SQLITE_SOUNDEX=1"
  PerformEnvironmentSet="true"
 />

Comment: Can't help you there. Just be very careful, and be sure you modified build correctly in all requred places.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i can't add a vote since it's my first question. take care man!!

Comment: I'm a Java developer, was always thinking that Java is the worst mess but .NET seems to top it ;) 
Anyway, I have no idea and time to recompile stuff I don't know, so what about this "modify you query"? I just want to use a simple performant full text search, 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fullText USING fts4 (mediaID TEXT PRIMARY KEY, fullText TEXT)' I would be able to do anywhere in SQLite, can you give me a hint how to do it using .NET?